# how to index a boolean in redis FT.SEARCH

Tags: redis

hi guy's i'am new on redis. i'am using redis with python.

i was read the documentation about making an index and scheme. i want to ask, why i can't add schema about field with bool value.

```
  "type": "inCall",
  "serviceId": "658006e463386df30aa4342e",
  "companyId": "6344ee8e91d97e8214cd5f25",
  "serviceScheduleId": "65805f8063386df30aa43436",
  "branchOfficeId": "657fe4ba771ca41487a2f4f4",
  "queueSessionId": "65f25502024cbdbb05da3d16",
  "isDisplay": true
```

why i can make sceme for field isDisplay with bool ? is there any solution to indexing bolean on redis

this the code to make scheme and index in redis with python

```
async def redisDataStream_create_index_queue()->bool:
    indexAvailable = False
    needCreateIndex = False
    try:
        idxInfo = await redisAccessStream.ft(redisDataStreamIndexQueue).info()
        indexAvailable = True
        MSLogger().success(f"Redis index already exists {redisDataStreamIndexQueue}", foreground="blue")
    except Exception as err:
        errStr = str(err).lower()
        # search in lowercase
        needCreateIndex = errStr == Redis_Error_Unknown_index_Name
        if not needCreateIndex:
            MSLogger().error(errStr)
            raise err
    if (not indexAvailable) and (needCreateIndex):
        schema =(
            TagField("$.monitorId", as_name="monitorId"),
            TextField("$.type", as_name="type"),
            TagField("$.serviceId", as_name="serviceId"),
            TextField("$.data.checkInTime", as_name="checkInTime"),
            TextField("$.data.destinationLoket", as_name="destinationLoket"),
            TextField("$.data.queueType", as_name="queueType"),
            TagField("$.data.user.userId", as_name="userId"),
            TextField("$.data.user.name", as_name="name"),
            TagField("$.data.user.queueHistoryId", as_name="queueHistoryId"),
        )
        res = await redisAccessStream.ft(redisDataStreamIndexQueue).create_index(
            schema,
            definition=IndexDefinition(
                prefix=[redisDataStreamPrefix+":"],
                index_type=IndexType.JSON
            )
        )
```

and this the code when i insert a queue in redis

```
class RedisAccessHelper:
    @staticmethod
    async def InsertQueue(
        req: ContentQueueInCall
    ) -> bool:
        try:
            id=ObjectId()
            keyName = redisDataStreamPrefix + ":" + req.data.user.name
            await redisAccessStream.json().set(
                keyName,
                Path.root_path(),
                {
                    "monitorId": str(id),
                    "type":StreamStatus.inCall,
                    "isDisplay":req.isDisplay,
                    "data":{
                        "checkInTime":str(req.data.checkinTime),
                        "destinationLoket":req.data.destinationLoket,
                        "user":{
                            "userId":str(req.data.user.userId),
                            "name": req.data.user.name,
                            "address": req.data.user.address,
                            "queueHistoryId": str(req.data.user.queueHistoryId),
                            "customerUserType": req.data.user.customerUserType
                        },
                        "queueType": req.data.queueType
                    }
                }
            )
            # await redisAccessStream.expire(keyName, 60)
            return True
        except Exception as err:
            if Settings().project.dev_mode:
                MSLogger().exception(str(err), err, False)
            return False
```

Comment: Are you using Hashes or JSON?

Comment: Sorry. But that doesn't answer my question. Are you storing things in Redis using the Hash type or the JSON type?

Comment: sory ... i'am storing using JSON @GuyRoyse

Comment: Redis an index a boolean if you declare it as a TAG field. Can you share your code as well so I can see what might be wrong?